# I have two operating systems, ubuntu and Windows. Jupyterlab opens files in ubuntu but I want to work in windows. How can I do it?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I have two operating systems, ubuntu and Windows. Jupyterlab opens files in ubuntu but I want to work in windows. How can I do it?. My files on Ubuntu show up but not the files on windows.

I've looked in many places in the settings but I can't fix it.